# IOError: stream is closed or unusable on a new genie App

Tags: julia

I created a new Genie App as described [here](https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/guides/Working_With_Genie_Apps.html). :

```
Genie.newapp("MyGenieApp")
```

with routes.jl looking like that:

```
using Genie.Router

route("/") do
  serve_static_file("welcome.html")
end

route("/hello")do
    "Welcome to Genie"
end
```

But when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/ , the generic 404-Not-Found Page is shown, and this error is printed to the console:

```
julia> ┌ Error: / 404
└ @ Genie.Router C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\Genie\1gtMT\src\Router.jl:150
┌ Error: error handling request
│   exception =
│    IOError: stream is closed or unusable
│    Stacktrace:
│     [1] check_open at .\stream.jl:328 [inlined]
│     [2] uv_write_async(::Sockets.TCPSocket, ::Ptr{UInt8}, ::UInt64) at .\stream.jl:961
│     [3] uv_write(::Sockets.TCPSocket, ::Ptr{UInt8}, ::UInt64) at .\stream.jl:924
│     [4] unsafe_write(::Sockets.TCPSocket, ::Ptr{UInt8}, ::UInt64) at .\stream.jl:1007
│     [5] unsafe_write at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\ConnectionPool.jl:174[inlined]
│     [6] macro expansion at .\gcutils.jl:91 [inlined]
│     [7] write at .\strings\io.jl:186 [inlined]
│     [8] writeheaders(::HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket}, ::HTTP.Messages.Response) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\Messages.jl:439
│     [9] startwrite(::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request,HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket}}) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\Streams.jl:85
│     [10] handle(::HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Genie.AppServer.var"#6#12"}, ::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request,HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket}}) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\Handlers.jl:278
│     [11] #4 at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\Handlers.jl:345 [inlined]
│     [12] macro expansion at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\HTTP\nMACo\src\Servers.jl:367 [inlined]
│     [13] (::HTTP.Servers.var"#13#14"{HTTP.Handlers.var"#4#5"{HTTP.Handlers.RequestHandlerFunction{Genie.AppServer.var"#6#12"}},HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket},HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Request,HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{Sockets.TCPSocket}}})() at .\task.jl:333
```

Does someone have a clue, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
Genie.newapp("MyGenie App")
```

instead of using CamelCase, I actually hat a space in here. Because Genie creates files and variables with this name, a space is not allowed here.

Comment: Adrian here, creator of Genie. Thanks for following up with the solution! Great catch! It would be super useful to extend the Generator to disallow spaces, either by erroring out and aborting -- or we could also just replace the space with an `_`. 

I'm making a note to add this feature, but if you want to contribute to Genie and can make a PR, I'd be very happy to merge it. Thanks again!